# Python outer for loop skipping every other element

Tags: python, nested-loops

I was trying to write a basic implementation of a deterministic Miller-Rabin test but my limited Python background is getting in the way. It seems that, in the section of the program pasted below, the outer for loop is skipping over every other element after the inner while loop completes. Any ideas as to why this is the case?

```
for integer in integers:
    print("The current integer is " + str(integer))
    i = 0
    while i < len(powers):
        print(str(integer) + "^" + str(powers[i]) + " + 1 mod N =")
        print((pow(integer,powers[i],N) + 1)%N)     
        if (pow(integer,powers[i],N) + 1)%N == 0:
            integers.remove(integer)
            i += 1
            break
        else:
            i += 1
```

Comment: Did you forget to add an indentation after the for loop or did it got removed when you paste it here?

Comment: @AquaticallyChallengedFish: Sorry, the indentations were lost after pasting. Fixed.

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete. What are the values of `integers`, `powers`, etc.? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably has to do with modifying your iterator mid iteration: `integers.remove(integer)` If this is indeed the case, you could just iterate an index..

Comment: @RoryDaulton it's a miller-rabin primality test... it's quite obvious what they represent

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks, that's it. A hacky way to resolve is to create a clone of the list integers and iterate over the clone while removing from the original list.

Comment: @Aaron: It's obvious what they *are supposed to* represent. Many bugs are hidden because the programmer makes assumptions about what the current value of a variable is.

Answer (score -5):

Put the `i += 1` outside the `if` and `else` statements

So

```
for integer in integers:
    print("The current integer is " + str(integer))
    i = 0
    while i < len(powers):
        print(str(integer) + "^" + str(powers[i]) + " + 1 mod N =")
        print((pow(integer,powers[i],N) + 1)%N)     
        if (pow(integer,powers[i],N) + 1)%N == 0:
            integers.remove(integer)

            break
        i += 1
```

Comment: this is syntactically identical to the OP's code..